# MVC: Algorithm uses multiple models

Tags: node.js, algorithm, mongodb, model-view-controller

I'm building a simple shopping cart recommendation engine. I'd like to adhere to strict MVC.

So far, the models are: `User`, `Items` (very simple, a `user` has a `shopping cart`:[] property, and `Items` contain information such as the `name`, `cost`, `brand`).

I want to start recommending to users based on what they purchased before.

So far I have the following:

- View is the API interface.
- Controller interacts with the view, looks at the input, and fetches the correct data for simple CRUD requests.
- Model enforces database restrictions such as indexing, uniqueness, and other business logic.

Where should the algorithm go? Since it touches both `users` and `items`, would it make sense to stick it in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where should the algorithm go?

What semantic concept does it apply to?  In the business context in which this algorithm executes, what is the user doing?

If the user is looking at a collection of items and that collection is used to populate a collection of related items, then I suspect the algorithm is semantically connected to `Item` and could go there.

If the user is looking at a user profile or some other thing which describes a user and that *user's* information is used to drive the recommendations, then it seems sensible to be a part of the `User`.

(Given the description in the question, I'm leaning toward the latter.)

It really just comes down to a question of semantics.  What is the aggregate root model in context when this operation is performed?  What is the contextual model being viewed or manipulated when this operation is performed?  What model's information drives this operation?  And so on, and so on.

Ultimately, it's a matter of preference.  It's a matter of how you decide to model the business domain being described in this code.  And, most importantly, it *can change*.  Today it may make sense to put this on the `User` model, tomorrow it might make sense to put it on the `Item` model, later it might make sense to build a different model just for this.  Maybe you start with having this operation on one model, but find later in implementation that you have to jump through hoops to access the operation and that it really ended up making more sense on another model.  So you refactor it.  As long as the domain modeling semantically makes sense, then it's correct.

> would it make sense to stick it in the controller?

I wouldn't think so, no.  Controllers are really for routing user requests to business logic.  They shouldn't *contain* business logic.  Models should.  (Or back-end services used by models, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm going to keep it in the models - after looking through the design, that approach seems to make the most sense, especially if business logic needs to change.